# How I can get only second part of relation?

Tags: slot

How I can get only the second part of this relation?
I want to get `Image` of function where `R` is a relation and `A` is a set.

```
Image[R_, A_] := Block[{}, For[i = 0, i < Length[A], i++, Select[#2[R]]]]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean the second part as in Part[R,2] or R[[2]]?

Comment: R[[2]] . For example relation [1->3,2->4] Second parts are 3 and 4.

Comment: `Last /@ {1 -> 3, 2 -> 4}`

Comment: Last /@ R  Why it doesn't work ?

Comment: @J.Doe Check `FullForm@R`.

Comment: First, it is better not to use `Image` as the name of a user-defined function, because it has built-in meanings. Second, what do you mean by a "relation"? *Mathematica* has no such a construct, I suppose.

Comment: Yes but we use private packages like relations etc

Comment: Seems you're looking for `R={1->2,3->4}; Values[R]`?

Comment: I'm looking for image of a function that mean form  R={1->2,3->4}; I should get 2 and 4.

Answer (score 3):

*Due to the policy of this forum I cannot add comments, so I type here.*

In order to get from `R={1->2,3->4}` 2 and 4 you can always use `R[[;;,2]]`.
I do not know how helpful it is for your main problem, which I do not understand correctly, maybe.

If `A` is a set (a `List`?), e.g., `{1,2,3}`, and `R` is a set of rules, e.g., `{1->2,2->3,3->4}`, you could use `A/.R` to get the ''Image'' `{2,3,4}`.
Is that what you are looking for?

If not, please be a bit more specific about what is your input and wished output.

Comment: I should write `Block[{},Print[A/.R]]`?

Comment: It depends on what you would like to do with the result. If you just want to print it out on the screen, then it will do the job. Actually, it would do the job without the `Block` construction. However, if you would like to further process it, e.g., apply another mapping to obtain yet another image, you could go for something like `img1 = A/.R1`, and then you could print it with `Print[img1]`, but also further process it with, e.g., `img2 = img1/.R2`, and so on. If you prefer to have a function for that you can simply try `image[A_,R_] := A/.R`. As I mentioned, it depends on your precise goals